# Mysql query only echoing 1 column

Tags: mysql

For some reason the only row that is echoing is the user_id column, everything else is just blank. I tried a query with SELECT * and it still wasn't any different. Does anyone know what might be happening? I get the right results as it selects the one user in the table that meets the criteria. The problem is that the name and phone number are not echoing.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT fname, lname, user_id, phone FROM users WHERE `approved` = 0 AND `user_active` = 1 AND `declined` = 0");
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              echo '<div>' . $row['fname'] . ' ' . $row['lname'] . ' ' . '<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="../lookup/profile?' . $row['user_id'] . '">View Profile Here</a>' . ' ' . $row['phone'] . '</div>';
      }
```

Comment: Is the database populated?

Comment: yes because I get a result from the user_id, and when I change the conditions it has two results creating two divs instead of just one

Comment: It's been a long time since I used PHP, but I'm pretty sure you need [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), not array.

Comment: array definitely works, because I use it in many other places on my website

Comment: you sure with ``approved` = 0` and not ``approved` = 1` because i think you select acitived users and aproved

Comment: this is to select users that have not been approved yet, so that I can review their profile and then approve them

Comment: or maybe you need some OR and not AND statment ??

Comment: all of those conditions need to be true

Comment: the problem is not that results are not showing up, it's that it is not extracting the name and phone number

Comment: Do you get valid data if you execute that query directly against the mysql db rather than through your code?

Comment: does the query show some result when you execute it on mysql

Comment: It returns empty fields in those columns

Comment: @MichaelStClair what does that tell you?

Comment: that there is no info in the field, haha. I probably should go take a break outside.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT fname, lname, user_id, phone FROM users 
          WHERE `approved` = 0 AND `user_active` = 1 AND `declined` = 0  GROUP BY user_id");
```

Comment: is there really any difference if you use single or double quotes?

Comment: It didn't make a difference